# Lazy Load Select2 Mulitselect

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, lazy-loading, jquery-select2

I have a huge mulitselect list of over 29,000 options on my page. I am displaying them in a form using select2, but because there are so many options it slows down the page drastically. I know select2 supports lazy load, but I am not sure how to implement it in my form.

I am using this code in my functions.php to add the select dropdown to my form (only showing a couple options the rest are not necessary)

```
 add_filter( 'submit_job_form_fields', 'frontend_add_experience_field' );

function frontend_add_experience_field( $fields) {
$fields['job']['regions1'] = array(
'label'       => __( 'Farming Areas', 'job_manager' ),
'type'        => 'multiselect',
'required'    => true,
'name' => 'regions1',
'placeholder' => 'Select A City',
'priority'    => 8,
'options'     => array(

"Abanda, AL"=>"Abanda, AL",
"Abbeville, AL"=>"Abbeville, AL",
"Adamsville, AL"=>"Adamsville, AL",
"Addison, AL"=>"Addison, AL",
"Akron, AL"=>"Akron, AL",
"Alabaster, AL"=>"Alabaster, AL",
"Albertville, AL"=>"Albertville, AL",
"Alexander, AL"=>"Alexander, AL",
"Alexandria, AL"=>"Alexandria, AL",
"Aliceville, AL"=>"Aliceville, AL",
 ));

  return $fields; }
```

and this is my javascript to implement select2

```
<script>

jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#regions1").select2({
      placeholder: "Search for a City",
minimumInputLength: 4,
maximumSelectionLength: 4,
width: "200px",
 });
});
});

</script>
```

Seeing as on my page there are around 29,000 options, is lazy load the best way to implement select2 or is there a more efficient way of displaying the results without putting a huge load on the server?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use the `minimumInputLength` The huge list of options doesn't show until the user has typed a min length of characters. Hope that helps!

Comment: Don't forget to set `closeOnSelect:false` Coz with `minimumInputLength`, the user can't select multiple items at a time.

Comment: @Arsalan Thanks, but I have already set minimumInputLength as you can see the code above, my issue arises when the page initially loads, the entire list is loaded (which takes a while) and then converted to select2.

Comment: You should then populate the select box via ajax based on the input.
You can refer to this [Loading remote data](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Comment: @Arsalan Can you point me in the right direction on how to format my options to display it using ajax. The documentation doesn't explain this clearly?

Comment: @Itamar did you get this going?

Comment: You can try it https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax